# Folders inside VBA Projects Window have disappeared

Tags: excel, vba, project-structure

In VB Editor, inside the VBA Projects window, the folders have disappeared.  That is all the sheets used to be in a folder, all the user forms used to be in a second folder, all the modules used to be in a third folder.  Now all the sheets, user forms, and modules are all listed together with no separate folders.  It's totally alphabetical depending on the name of the sheet, user form, or module - which makes a bit of a jungle.  The lack of organizing folders is true even of ancient workbooks which makes me think that somehow I inadvertently toggled a switch which invokes/removes folders for the project window.
1- Is it harmful?
2- Any way out of this? Any way to get the organizing folders back?

All constructive ideas gratefully appreciated!
ToolMaven

Answer (score 2):

In the VBA-IDE you can toggle the view to display or hide the folders with the folder-icon above the list.

Comment: Thank you so very much.  I did find the little folder icon at the top of the project window in the IDE which toggles the folders in/out view.  I swear in many years I never knew that toggle icon existed.  Thanks again for pointing me in the right direction.